# error C2011: 'sockaddr' : 'struct' type redefinition. see declaration of 'sockaddr'

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, visual-studio-2012, static-linking

I use Visual Studio 2012 and trying to get static library [UDT](http://udt.sourceforge.net/) get to work. Unfortunately, i cannot compile project that links UDT lib to itself, i get 159 strange errors about type or macro redefinitions in windows SDK headers.

`c:\program files\windows kits\8.0\include\shared\ws2def.h(96): warning C4005: 'AF_IPX' : macro redefinition
2>          c:\program files\windows kits\8.0\include\um\winsock.h(452) : see previous definition of 'AF_IPX'
2>c:\program files\windows kits\8.0\include\shared\ws2def.h(136): warning C4005: 'AF_MAX' : macro redefinition
2>          c:\program files\windows kits\8.0\include\um\winsock.h(471) : see previous definition of 'AF_MAX'
2>c:\program files\windows kits\8.0\include\shared\ws2def.h(173): warning C4005: 'SO_DONTLINGER' : macro redefinition
2>          c:\program files\windows kits\8.0\include\um\winsock.h(394) : see previous definition of 'SO_DONTLINGER'
2>c:\program files\windows kits\8.0\include\shared\ws2def.h(217): error C2011: 'sockaddr' : 'struct' type redefinition
2>          c:\program files\windows kits\8.0\include\um\winsock.h(477) : see declaration of 'sockaddr'`

Previously removed some code which was defining dllexport/dllimport for each UDT function:

```
#define UDT_API // no dllimport/export
```

I checked that library always use #ifdef to check if file is already included.
And this error:

`windows kits\8.0\include\um\ws2tcpip.h(703): error C3861: 'WSASetLastError': identifier not found`

May reason be `const` keyword in that expression (somewhere inside udt):

```
UDT_API int bind(UDTSOCKET u, const struct sockaddr* name, int namelen);
```

What iam missing?

Comment: What can we do without a minimum code that reproduce the problem?

Comment: @Jepessen there is not code, i just cannot build project if it does `#include "udt.h"`. You can follow the link, download archive, untar, open in visual studio and change `udt` build type to `static library`.Then remove `dllimport/dllexport` expressions (there two, can be easily found) and should be just `#define UDT_API`. Then link udt to other empty project and do `include "udt.h"` in it.... That is what i did

Comment: I remember something about defining `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` before including the `windows.h` as it already includes `winsock` and there seems to be problems otherwise. Is this such a scenario? I don't know at the moment hence this is a comment and no answer...

Comment: @PuerNoctis you've pointed me to a right direction, now i can compile both my projects, but i cannot write UDT code because i cannot include winsock stuff to my code. If i type `#include <winsock2.h>` or
   `#include <ws2tcpip.h>`
   or `#include <wspiapi.h>`, i get same erros

Comment: Windows is notorious for being picky about the order of include files.  Bad design in my opinion.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you include winsock.h and winsock2.h make sure that you include winsock2.h first. If the includes are not so obvious you can check cpp files in question if you [compile them with /P](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z9z0bx6.aspx) and walk through the generated preprocessor output file.

Comment: Have just read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22517036/socket-errors-cant-get-functions-in-winsock2-h and no, that does not help..If i try to include any winsock header, i get 159 errors (like in linked question)

Comment: Did you check with `/P`?

Comment: UDT or my project? Where and *what* should i watch after build with /P?

Comment: Use `/P` for one (any you like) of the files that can't compile.

Comment: I just get this stupid another error. http://pastebin.com/6V5RdjQV I do not understand what does it mean.

Comment: That's not so bad. This means that the linker can't find the Output file. This is expected, as `/P` only write the preprocessed file but does not compile. Now look into the file that was written by the Compiler (file.i).

Comment: Sharing my method that solved my issue: 
1. turn on #include hierarchy(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137966/displaying-the-include-hierarchy-for-a-c-file-in-visual-studio#:~:text=It's%20under%20Project%20Settings%20%2D%3E%20Configuration,%3E%20Advanced%20%2D%3E%20Show%20Includes.).  2. reorder the include to resolve the issue:  My issue is due to winsoc2.h included after windows.h(https://www.sysnet.pe.kr/2/0/12438)

Answer (score 2):

Just to describe what problem was... Seems like i shouldnt include `udt.h` before any `winsock` headers. That's the fix:

```
 #ifndef WIN32
   #include <unistd.h>
   #include <cstdlib>
   #include <cstring>
   #include <netdb.h>
   #else
   #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
    #include <WinSock2.h>
    #include <WS2tcpip.h>
    #include <Windows.h>
   #endif

   #include <udt.h>
   #include <singleton.h>
   #include <excassert.h>
   #include <SharedUtility.h>

   #ifndef WIN32
   void* recvdata(void*);
   #else
   DWORD WINAPI recvdata(LPVOID);
   #endif
```